# WinRT async data load in constructor

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, async-await

I want to load some data in the constructor of a ViewModel but due to WinRT's async nature I am forced to use async methods. Unfortunately I cannot have an async constructor so I am trying to use the asynchronous method as a synchronous method. I'm sure there is a much better way of loading data (async) on application load but my mind is drawing a blank at the moment.

I'm either looking for a way to fix my app using the line of thought i'm going down, or to fix this permanently using a more appropriate method.

The code is very simple (even missing the ViewModel) just to demonstrate the issue I'm facing.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public string Data { get; set; }

    public DataService _dataService { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        _dataService = new DataService();
        var t = _dataService.GetData();

        Data = t.Result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.  The Parameter
    /// property is typically used to configure the page.</param>
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }


}

public class DataService
{
    public async Task<string> GetData()
    {
        //Force async
        await Task.Delay(1);

        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Kind Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wrote a recent blog post about [`async` in constructors](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html).

In short, I prefer an `async` factory method:

```
public sealed class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private readonly DataService _service;

  private MyViewModel(DataService service)
  {
    _service = service;
  }

  private async Task InitializeAsync()
  {
    var result = await _service.GetData(); // async initialization

    Data = result; // update data-bound properties with the results
  }

  // Data triggers INotifyPropertyChanged on write
  public string Data { get { ... } set { ... } }

  public static async Task<MyViewModel> CreateAsync()
  {
    var ret = new MyViewModel();
    await ret.InitializeAsync();
    return ret;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Forcing async methods to run synchronously usually leads to deadlocks, so I would not recommend that. The thing with view models is that they usually support change notifications through `INotifyPropertyChanged` `PropertyChanged` event, so there is no need to have all data available immediately. In fact if your data isn't hard-coded - you shouldn't expect to see the data immediately and you would most likely want to show a progress indicator while the data is loading. Thus...

In your constructor call an async initialization method without awaiting the result (since you can't await in a constructor) and in the initialization method when all data is available - assign it to property/properties that your view binds to, raise PropertyChanged event for these properties and hide the progress indicator by changing the view model property that controls its visibility.

Comment: Keep error handling in mind. If the `Task` returned by the `async` initialization method is never observed, any exceptions will be silently swallowed. So be sure to have a `try`/`catch` in your `InitializeAsync` or have another method `await` the result.

Comment: Of course. This applies regardless of whether the call is in an initializer or any other method that might lead to bad state.