# Reading a file with StreamReader line by line

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, streamreader

I am trying to read a simple text file line by line in Windows 8 C# file with StreamReader. I tried many solutions but non of it worked. Sometimes the file is read and sometimes it's not(the class is empty, only nulls). If the program is running it's never working but when I set up a debugger and use it to go line by line sometimes it works. Why is that? That's the source:

```
public async void read(string fileName)
    {

        string File = Path.Combine(Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path, "myfolder", fileName);

        StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(Path.GetDirectoryName(File));

        Stream s = await folder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(Path.GetFileName(File));
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(s);

        myClass.name = streamReader.ReadLine();
        myClass.desc = streamReader.ReadLine();
        myClass.number = int.Parse(streamReader.ReadLine());
        myClass.house = new House[myClass.number];

        for (int i = 0; i < myClass.number; i++)
        {
            myClass.house[i] = new House();
            myClass.house[i].name = streamReader.ReadLine();
            myClass.house[i].size = double.Parse(streamReader.ReadLine());
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only use `async void` if the function is an event handler (e.g. button press).  Generally, you should use `async Task` instead.

Change your method signature from `void` to `Task`:

```
public async Task read(string fileName)
```

Then from your calling code, `await` it:

```
await yourclass.read("c:\\my_filename.txt");
```

Comment: I tried it, but I would like to call the method when the whole page is initialized but when I write the "await read("filetoRead.txt")" in page constructor it says that the 'await' operator can only be used within an async method but from what I know constructor cannot be async. Am I right or I missed something?

Comment: @user2202439 - regarding the async constructor: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449349/winrt-async-data-load-in-constructor

Comment: Thank you for help. I read Stephen's blog several times but I still cannot write it correctly. I have private `async Task<MyClass> InitializeAsync()`, where I only read data with StreamReader and retrun this and `public static async Task<MyClass> CreateAsync()` where I call InitializeAsync with await. I call those methods in code by `public static async Task UseMyClassAsync()
        {
            instance = await MyClass.CreateAsync();
        }` and it still have problems. What am I doing wrong? Can you give me an example how it should look like?

Comment: @user2202439 If you are trying to call `await MyClass.CreateAsync()` from a constructor, it just cannot be done. You have to find some other method where you can call it. For example, if your caller is a UI page, you could call `MyClass.CreateAsync` from either `LoadState` or `OnNavigateTo`. This assumes that your project was created using one of the standard templates (e.g. Grid or Split App template). Beyond that I cannot write an example, because I would only be guessing at what you are trying to do. You would be better off asking a new question, and providing more context.

Comment: You are totally right. I completely forgot about `OnNavigatedTo`. I overrided it as async method and it works beautiful now. Thank you for your help and time once again.