# HubSection with compiled binding

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp, compiled-bindings

I'm trying to grasp the new compiled bindings, but right at the start I get stopped by this simple problem.

I have `Hub` control with one `HubSection`. The content of this section is an `ItemsControl` that needs to bind to view models' observable collection. I can't get this binding to work as I expect it to.

```
<Pivot x:Name="rootPivot" Style="{StaticResource TabsStylePivotStyle}">
    <PivotItem>
        <Hub>
            <HubSection Header="News">
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:HomePage">
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.NewsItems, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

`ViewModel` property is just a property and is instantiated before `InitializeComponents()` call. `NewsItems` is observable collection inside view model that is filled after the page has loaded - asynchronously (web request).

What am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT: Code-behind**

HomePage.xaml.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Home pag view.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class HomePage : Page
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="HomePage"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public HomePage()
    {
        // Retrieve view model
        this.ViewModel = ViewModelResolver.Home;

        // Trigger view model loaded on page loaded
        this.Loaded += (sender, args) => this.ViewModel.LoadedAsync();

        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the view model.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The view model.
    /// </value>
    public IHomeViewModel ViewModel { get; }
}
```

HomePageViewModel.cs

```
/// <summary>
/// Home view model.
/// </summary>
public sealed class HomeViewModel : IHomeViewModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs on page loaded.
    /// </summary>
    public async Task LoadedAsync()
    {
        // Retrieve news items
        var news = await new NewsService().GetNewsAsync();
        foreach (var newsItem in news)
            this.NewsItems.Add(newsItem);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the news items.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The news items.
    /// </value>
    public ObservableCollection<IFeedItem> NewsItems { get; } = new ObservableCollection<IFeedItem>();
}
```

Comment: You might want to show your code-behind code.

Comment: Does this help? @JustinXL

Comment: @JustinXL I don't. Only this method is called on Loaded so I don't care if it continues before view models' loading finishes.

Comment: Putting other issues aside, you are doing a *fire and forget* on an async task which is wrong. There are plenty of samples on SO for doing this properly. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14449349/winrt-async-data-load-in-constructor

Comment: `this.Loaded += async (sender, args) => await this.ViewModel.LoadedAsync();` Would be better? The effect is the same when you only call one method you don't need to _(a)wait_ for it tof finish. I didn't find any other way of calling async mathods from `void Loaded` method. That is not the issue here for sure. @JustinXL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86946/discussion-between-aleksandar-toplek-and-justin-xl).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is indeed an interesting question. I guess the issue is that, unlike typical `DataTemplate` like the following (see its parent `ListView` is binding to some known data `Model.Items`)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Model.Items}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Item">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

your top level `DataTemplate` however, doesn't know where the data comes from.

So the fix is to tell the `HubSection` to bind the right data - in this case, the `HomePage.xaml.cs` instance. So, try adding this to your `Hub`

```
<Hub DataContext="{x:Bind}">
```

Or simply add

```
this.InitializeComponent();
this.DataContext = this;
```

Either way should fix your issue.

Comment: Also I'd still recommend you to rethink how you call the service, but that's unrelated to the question. The link I provided earlier should give you some hints.

Comment: This is just and example. I omitted bunch of code. I use DI, facades, etc. in real app. @Justin XL

Comment: This solved my problem, but an additional note: I can't use a `<DataTemplate>` without `x:DataType="{ TheType }"` so to getaround that I changed from `<ListView ItemsSource="{ x:Bind MyWorkStories, Mode=TwoWay }">` to `<ListView ItemsSource="{ Binding MyWorkStories, Mode=TwoWay }">` and I can now have a blank `<DataTemplate>` surrounding the ListView as a HubSection requires it.